# Lifting Property of flips

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, projective-module

I am trying to understand the concept of flips before learning the Bass Cancellation theorem. Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring  and  $P$ be a projective $R$ module. Let $p,q \in P$ , $\phi \in Hom(P,R)$ and $a \in R$. The automorphisms $(p,a) \mapsto (p+aq,a)$ and $(p,a) \mapsto (p,a+\phi(p))$ are called $\textbf{Flips}$.

Now the author says that they have a lifting property: If $I$ is an ideal  of $R$, then every flip of $P/IP \bigoplus R/I$ over the ring $R/I$ can be lifted to that of $P \bigoplus R$. I am not understanding how should I prove this. Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Comment:   So "a flip of $P\oplus R$" is just any automorphism of the form $(p,a)\mapsto (p+aq,a)$ for some $q\in P$, OR of the form $(p,a)\mapsto (p, a+\phi(p))$ for some $\phi: P\to R$?  It's a bit unusual to make a definition like this for a union of two somewhat different sets of functions.  (I might distinguish them with a modifier, somehow.)

Comment: I would guess this follows from a combination of the facts that $R/I$ modules (and homomorphisms) are $R$ modules (and homomorphisms) in the natural way, and that $R\oplus P$ is $R$ projective, and that these flips are surjections.  or maybe some pithier homological algebra explanation!